# How to access a page behind proxy

Tags: c#, authentication, webproxy

My code is working if I hardcode my credentials

```
string url;

string proxyAddress;
string user ;
string password;
Stream objStream;
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy(proxyAddress, true);
proxyObject.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Proxy = proxyObject;
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
objStream= response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(objStream);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.Write(text);
Console.Read();
Console.ReadKey();
```

but what I want is that I want to access that page using my windows credentials. Because in our company we use same credentials for web access.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
proxyObject.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: I tried but I get error
Status: ProtocolError
Message: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy authentication required

Comment: @user2983359 And what is the context of the code? Is that a GUI application or code running in IIS? What user context is the code running as?

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to access the page in a console application.

Comment: @user2983359 And the console application is running under the same user as the one whose credentials you used hardcoded? What is the url given?

Comment: yes the console application is running under the same user.

Comment: @user2983359 it is possible that the proxy software that is used does not support integrated authentication whereby you can authenticate yourself by simply being logged into windows, but just uses the same username and password or does itself check the username and password against the Active Directory. Please specify in the question which proxy software is used and how it is configured.

Comment: At my compnay we are using AXS GUARD Gatekeeper.

Comment: if I try to send a request using curl then there is no issue. I have tried with my credentials and with a new dummy credentials as well and it worked